# Two possible Sudo passwords in shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, passwords, sudo

I have a problem with Mac computers being deployed with two possible root admin passwords. I'm trying to create a shell script to uninstall an application, and need to inject both passwords. If "password 1" is correct, the script finishes without any errors. This is where I am now. Any suggestions?

```
echo "password 1" | sudo "command"
if [ $? –ne 0 ]; then
## last command didn’t work, let’s try another password
  echo "password 2" | sudo "command"
fi
```

output

```
RT20787-MAC:desktop tsstech$ sh Uninstall_script.sh 
Password:Sorry, try again.
Password:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
Uninstall_script.sh: line 21: [: –ne: binary operator expected
Password:
```

Comment: Have you considered using passwordless `sudo`? If you're willing to put your password in a shell script that anyone can read, you might as well just not require the password at all. Here's a [quick tutorial](http://wiki.summercode.com/sudo_without_a_password_in_mac_os_x) that might help you.

Comment: You need to use `sudo -S` for it to read the password from standard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your test :

```
if [ $? –ne 0 ] #–ne: binary operator expected
```

Add quote to $? :

```
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]
```

or use the != operator :

```
if [ $? != 0 ]
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any circumstances where `$?` can expand to a null string, so the quotes shouldn't make any difference. `-ne` is technically the correct choice, although again I'm not aware of any value that `$?` can produce that would cause `-ne` and `!=` to produce different results.

Comment: (Although, the given error message pretty strongly implies that `$?` *is* expanding to an empty string somehow.)

Answer (score 2):

Just provide both passwords to the one sudo. My sudo needs the option `-S` to read passwords from stdin.

```
echo -e "password 1\npassword 2" | sudo -S "command"
```

This assumes your `"command"` doesnt need to read from stdin, but see also the comments below.

Comment: "the command doesnt read stdin" `sudo` remembers the successful attempt for some time. So this could be an easier work-around: `echo -e "password1\npassword2" | sudo true && sudo command`... `/bin/true` does not consume `stdin`...